# Javascript Promise not entering the then()

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an issue with JavaScript Promise where in one of the promise is not moving into then()

Below is the code I am trying to accomplish.

Background: I have not used Promise before, but have read through few articles.

```
    function doStart(){        
    var loadedMap = loadBasemap([layer0]);
    loadedMap.then(function (v) {
            view = loadView(MAP_CANVAS_ID, map);
            ...
        });
    ...
}
    
 function loadBasemap(layers) {
    if (LayerSettings && LayerSettings.hasOwnProperty('basemap') && LayerSettings.basemap.hasOwnProperty('baseMapLayers')) {
        new Promise(function () {
            updateToDefaultLayerSetting();
        }).then(function () {
            map = new Map({
                basemap: Basemap.fromJSON(LayerSettings.basemap),
                layers: layers
            });
        });
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(map));
    }
    else {...}
}

async function updateToDefaultLayerSetting() {
    console.log("Calling default");
    const result = await actionDefaultBasemap();
    console.log(result);
}

var defaultBasemap;
function actionDefaultBasemap() {
    let portalA = new Portal(portalConfig);
    
    new Promise(function () {
        portalA.load().then(function () {
            defaultBasemap = portalA.useVectorBasemaps ? portalA.defaultVectorBasemap : portalA.defaultBasemap;
        }).then(function () {
            if (LayerSettings.basemap.baseMapLayers[0].hasOwnProperty('url') && typeof defaultBasemap.resourceInfo !== "undefined") {
                LayerSettings.basemap.baseMapLayers[0].id = defaultBasemap.resourceInfo.data.baseMapLayers[0].id;
                LayerSettings.basemap.baseMapLayers[0].title = defaultBasemap.resourceInfo.data.baseMapLayers[0].title;
                LayerSettings.basemap.baseMapLayers[0].url = defaultBasemap.resourceInfo.data.baseMapLayers[0].url;
            }
        });
    })

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(defaultBasemap));
}
```

Execution Order is as below:

1. doStart()
2. loadBasemap(layers)
3. updateToDefaultLayerSetting()
4. actionDefaultBasemap()

The process is execulting the then() inside actionDefaultBasemap() but not reaching the then() in loadBasemap().

Not sure where the process is breaking. I would need the map object to be returned to

```
view = loadView(MAP_CANVAS_ID, map);
```

Any advise would be helpful.

Comment: I think you need to read more articles. The callback function passed into `new Promise()` has to accept the `resolve` and `reject` parameters, and call them as appropriate. Otherwise the Promise will never resolve (or reject) and nothing will happen.

Comment: `new Promise(function () { updateToDefaultLayerSetting(); })` - you're never `resolve`ing the promise!

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Also note that `map` and `baseMap` would not be defined at the point where you are returning new Promise. All in all, you'd need to do `return updateToDefaultLayerSetting().then(function () { return new Map(...) })` — this creates the promise from the async function call, `then` makes a new promise which awaits the previous one, then that promise gets returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Promise.then not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896030/promise-then-not-executing)

Answer (score 5):

```
new Promise(function () {
   updateToDefaultLayerSetting();
}).then(...
```

The `new Promise` constructor exists for one reason: to wrap a promise around something that is not using promises (eg, a callback). If you're going to use it for that, you need to call either the `resolve` or `reject` callbacks, as in the following:

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
      resolve('success!');
    } else {
      reject('error');
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Your code never calls `resolve` or `reject`, and so the code in the `.then` can never happen

But you actually don't need to call `new Promise` at all, because you already have promises! `updateToDefaultLayerSetting` returns a promise (which you can tell because it's an async function), which means that loadBaseMap can be written as the following:

```
function loadBasemap(layers) {
  if (LayerSettings && LayerSettings.hasOwnProperty("basemap") && LayerSettings.basemap.hasOwnProperty("baseMapLayers")) {
    return updateToDefaultLayerSetting().then(function () {
      return new Map({
        basemap: Basemap.fromJSON(LayerSettings.basemap),
        layers: layers,
      });
    });
  } else {...}
}
```

In the above code, calling `.then` on a promise creates a new promise. That new promise will resolve with whatever is eventually returned by the callback function. So loadBasemap is returning a promise which will resolve to a `Map`.

If you prefer to do the same with async/await (i know i do), that will look like:

```
async function loadBasemap(layers) {
  if (LayerSettings && LayerSettings.hasOwnProperty("basemap") && LayerSettings.basemap.hasOwnProperty("baseMapLayers")) {
    await updateToDefaultLayerSetting();
    return new Map({
      basemap: Basemap.fromJSON(LayerSettings.basemap),
      layers: layers,
    });
  } else {...}
}
```

---

`actionDefaultBasemap` will need some rewriting as well, which i have not included. It has the same problem: creating new promises where none are needed, and then never resolving the new promise. portalA.load() already returns a promise, so build off of that.

If you prefer `.then` syntax, call `.then` on the promise and in the callback return what you want the new promise to resolve to. If you prefer `async`/`await` syntax, await the promise and then return what you want the function's promise to resolve to.